# In Scala is there a nicer a way to express the following inheritance?

Tags: scala

In my base class I have

```
  trait EventReceiver  {

    def onStart(start: Start) {

    }

  }
```

I define

```
  def benchmark = new EventReceiver {}
```

since I need to do some processing in the base class.  In the child class which my clients use they do something similar to the following

```
override def benchmark = new EventReceiver {
    override def onStart(start: Start) {
      println("benchmark start")
    }
}
```

I view this bit as a bit clunky

```
override def benchmark = new EventReceiver { ...
```

Is there a nicer way to express this?  Ideally it would be something like

```
singleword {
    override def onStart(start: Start) {
      println("benchmark start")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example,

```
def singleword(fOnStart: Start => Unit) =
  new EventReceiver {
    override def onStart(start: Start) { fOnStart(start) }
  }
```

then,

```
singleword { start =>
  println("benchmark started")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `EventReceiver` doesn't do anything else than provide a single `def` it can rather **be** a single function.

```
object Base {
   def singleWord(receiver: Start => Unit) = new Base {
      override def benchmark = receiver
   }
}

abstract class Base {
   def benchmark: (Start => Unit)
}
```

Now you can instantiate instances of your subclasses like this:

```
import Base._
val subInstance = singleWord { start =>
   println("benchmark" + start)
}
```

If you EventReceiver does provide further functionality you can still use this construct, but the code in your "library" will get a bit uglier. It'll work though.